# Terminate hung query (idle in transaction)

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Heroku with the Crane Postgres option and I was running a query on the database from my local machine when my local machine crashed. If I run

```
select * from pg_stat_activity
```

one of the entries has

```
<IDLE> in transaction
```

in the current_query_text column.

As a result, I can't drop the table that was being written to by the query that was terminated. I have tried using pg_cancel_backend(N) and it returns True but nothing seems to happen.

How can I terminate this process so that I can drop the table?

Comment: Maybe the question should be rephrased to "how do I terminate my own query when having neither root access to the postgres server nor superuser access to the database".  It seems like a very good question indeed ... and I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

*This is a general PostgreSQL answer, and not specific to Heroku*

---

### Possibly easiest quickfix

The simple-stupid answer to this question may be ... just restart postgresql!

Here is another way of quickly killing all long-lasting "idle in transaction":

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity
WHERE state in ('<IDLE> in transaction', 'idle in transaction')
  AND now()-xact_start>interval '1 minute';
```

### More complicated quickfix

Find the PID by running this sql*):

```
SELECT now()-xact_start as trans_time, pid, query from pg_stat_activity
  WHERE state != 'idle' ORDER BY xact_start;
```

You'll find the pid in the first (left) column, and the first (top) row is likely to be the query you'd like to terminate.  Use `select *` to get more information about the queries.  I'll assume the pid is 1234 below.

You may cancel a query through SQL (i.e. without shell access) as long as it's yours*) or you have super user access:

```
select pg_cancel_backend(1234);
```

That's a "friendly" request to cancel the 1234-query, and with some luck it will disappear after a while.  If required, the following is more of a "hard terminate" command which could cause it to cancel more quickly:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(1234);
```

If you have shell access and root or postgres permissions you can also do it from the shell.  To "cancel" one can do:

```
kill -INT 1234
```

and to "terminate", simply:

```
kill 1234
```

**DO NOT:**

```
kill -9 1234
```

... that will often result in the the whole postgres server going down in flames, then you may as well restart postgres.  Postgres is pretty robust, so the data won't be corrupted, but I'd recommend against using "kill -9" in any case :-)

### Permanent fix - dealing with the root cause

A long-lasting "idle in transaction" often means that the transaction was not terminated with a "commit" or a "rollback", meaning that the application is buggy or not properly designed to work with transactional databases - so to properly fix this issue, it's needed to ensure the application always does a `commit` or a `rollback` after running queries, even read-only queries (it's also possible to enable auto-commit).

Long-lasting "idle in transaction" should be avoided, as it may (dependent on your usage pattern) cause major performance problems.

---

**Footnotes**: The query may need mending on very old or future versions of PostgreSQL, and on very old versions of PostgreSQL only superuser can cancel queries.

Comment: I tried pg_cancel_backend to no avail. I don't have shell access and I'm not a superuser so I can't send a SIGKILL using pg_terminate_backend

Comment: Which version of postgres are you using?  (hint: `select version()`).  Do you get any error messages when using `pg_cancel_backend`?

Comment: Made an attempt to use pg_cancel_backend myself, so got error message "must be superuser to signal other server processes" ... meaning that apparently you'll need either root access on the server or db access through some postgres super user (i.e. postgres user) to kill your own query.  That seems to suck a bit :-(

Comment: it turns out that the processes were being cancelled by pg_cancel_backend but the queries still show in pg_stat_activity for a while

Comment: Perhaps it's specific to Heroku.  As far as I can see, under ordinary postgres it's really needed to be superuser to kill a stuck process (I'm testing with "select pg_sleep(3600);" on pg 8.4, and I get "ERROR:  must be superuser to signal other server processes").  Though, then again "idle in transaction" is not quite the same.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical that long lasting "idle in transaction" connections harm performance, any benchmarks for that?

Comment: I haven't done any benchmarks, but I've seen dramatic degradation of performance after such a thing has been allowed to sit there for days.  YMMV, it does of course depend on the write activity, I suppose it doesn't matter at all if the database is a constant read-only thing.  Vacuums also won't be able to remove "dead" rows visible to the long-lasting transaction

Comment: Is there any reason why one should favor pg_cancel_backend over pg_terminate_backend?
Never mind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866865/difference-between-terminating-and-cancelling-a-process

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid int)
```

More about this you can find [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE). This should be 'cleaner' solution of this problem than killing process by system.

Comment: Please add how to get your pid to your answer

Answer (score 21):

You can install the [`heroku-pg-extras`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras) add-on and run the following command to get the PID:

```
heroku pg:locks --app <your-app>
```

Then just do:

```
heroku pg:kill <pid> --app <your-app>
```

**NOTE**: `--force` option can be used to issue pg_terminate_backend which drops the entire connection for that query.

If `heroku pg:locks` does not list anything, try `heroku pg:ps`.

For more information check out:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-ps-pg-kill-pg-killall

Comment: Thank you. I still can't terminate the transaction/PID though... my computer did a hardware freeze during an import and I am unable to terminate the PID. :(

Answer (score 2):

To terminate all running queries:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active';
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319597/how-to-stop-kill-a-query-in-postgresql#comment90637769_35319597)