# Process running in backend after killing

Tags: unix, kettle, pdi

I had ran 1 kitchen.sh  command in unix server which  will do some INSERT/UPDATE data loading from 1 table to another based on some logic.
But since the input data is having huge count.So i had to kill the process in between by the following command

**kill -9 pid**(pid =process id)

and then i checked in the server with  **ps -ef | grep kitchen**   command and that process was not showing.so i thought it got killed.

But i noticed now that daily few records are updating and somehow the process is running in backend.Any solutions as how to check that and how to resolve it

Comment: it seems your transformation never ends. what happens if your run this under spoon.sh ?

Comment: The problem wes not about re-executing ,but after killing the rocess how it is updating... and how to resolve that

Comment: i understood, i am trying to explain that is something bad on your transformation, and this same thing happened to me. pentaho never ending should be considered as an error. Double check your db indexes.

Comment: The problem has been solved.I checked with pg_activity and in db backend it was in idle in transaction mode.So this problem occured.So i killed it .....
This link helped me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291456/heroku-postgres-terminate-hung-query-idle-in-transaction

Answer (score 0):

double check the indexes of your db table, your could have huge improvement on insert/update after adding the proper indexes.