# How to stop/kill a query in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

This question is while postmaster is running your query in the background, how to kill or stop it?

For example, your shell or any frontend may be disconnected due to network issue, you cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to kill it but the background postmaster is still running your query. How to kill it?

Comment: SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid), pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active';

Comment: @codersofthedark I doubt that pg_terminate_backend will wait for pg_cancel_backend in that case.
So it's almost the same as "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active';"
Am I wrong?

BTW: That's quite awesome anyway. Would be cool if that would be listed as an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 756):

What I did is first check what are the running processes by

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active';
```

Find the process you want to kill, then type:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(<pid of the process>)
```

This basically "starts" a request to terminate gracefully, which may be satisfied after some time, though the query comes back immediately.

If the process cannot be killed, try:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(<pid of the process>)
```

Comment: `pg_cancel_backend` does work but it takes awhile (if it returns true, like a graceful cleanup).  pg_terminate_backend is more like a "hard kill" as it were, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11292126/32453

Comment: Blocking pids can be found by running the "Сombination of blocked and blocking activity" query on the https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring page.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL), `pg_cancel_backend` will stop the current query in that process, but `pg_terminate_backend` will finish the session in that proceses. A connected app can recover from a failed query, but to recover from a closed session it would need to open a new cursor. Use both wisely.

Comment: To cancel all requests except itself use: `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active' and pid <> pg_backend_pid();`

Comment: Is there another way if these ones both fail to cancel?

Comment: Another recommended thread to read: https://serverfault.com/questions/415188/kill-9-a-postgres-process

Comment: @Luffydude `sudo kill -9 <pid>`