# Alter Table in PostgreSQL takes a long time in local

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter

I have installed `PostgreSQL 10.6` in my Macbook Pro. I am able to login  and perform all the `DML` and `DDL` operations. However, I am not able to add a new column to an existing table. The following query takes forever to execute.

```
alter table PT add column PT_DATE timestamp;
```

The above query does not complete at all. There are no rows in the table. There are no queries running against the `database`. Am I doing something wring?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, so my guess is that there is some other problem/process happening?  Are there any other concurrent jobs on Postgres which might be causing this simple `ALTER` statement to hang?

Comment: most like it another process has lock on your table. check if have another process running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319597/how-to-stop-kill-a-query-in-postgresql

Comment: What error do you receive from server?