# Killing a particular sql query in postgres

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

To kill a query with a certain string in mysql, I can do the following:

```
kill_string = 'LONG-QUERY'
cursor = self.conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW FULL processlist")
for _row in cursor.fetchall():
    _id = _row[0]
    _query = _row[-1] or ''
    if kill_string in _query:
        cursor.execute('KILL %s' % _id)
```

What would be the equivalent in Postgres?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku Postgres - terminate hung query (idle in transaction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291456/heroku-postgres-terminate-hung-query-idle-in-transaction)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite similar, the commands would be:

```
kill_string = 'LONG-QUERY'

cursor.execute("SELECT pid, query FROM pg_stat_activity")
for _row in cursor.fetchall():
    _id = _row[0]
    _query = _row[-1] or ''
    if kill_string in _query:
        cursor.execute('SELECT pg_terminate_backend(%s)' % _id)
```