# How to safely kill a query which has timed out

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timeout

I'm using PostgreSQL JDBC, and I have a connection for some select and insert queries. Some queries take some time, so I added a timeout. The problem is that the timeout closes the connection, but the query is still executed in the db server and it creates locks.

A simplified code for the problem (The real code is much complex and bigger, but it doesn't matter):

```
    PGPoolingDataSource source = new PGPoolingDataSource();
    source.setUrl(url);
    source.setUser(user);
    source.setPassword(password);
    source.setMaxConnections(10);
    source.setSocketTimeout(5); // Timeout of 5 seconds

    // Insert a row data, and make timeout
    Connection con = source.getConnection();
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    try {
        Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
        st2.execute("insert into data.person values (4, 'a')");

        Statement st3 = con.createStatement();
        st3.executeQuery("select pg_sleep(200)"); // A query which takes a lot of time and causes a timeout
        con.commit();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        if (!con.isClosed()) {
            con.rollback();
            con.close();
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    Connection con2 = source.getConnection();
    con2.setAutoCommit(false);
    try {
        Statement st2 = con2.createStatement();

        // This insert query is locked because the query before is still executed, and the rollback didn't happen yet, and the row with the id of 4 is not released
        st2.execute("insert into data.person values (4, 'b')");
        con2.commit();
        con2.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        if (!con2.isClosed()) {
            con2.rollback();
            con2.close();
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(`data.person` is a table with `id` and `name`.)

The timeout closes the connection, and it didn't even get to the line `con.rollback();` . I have read that when an exception occurs on a query it does rollback in the background, so it is ok.

But the query takes a lot of time (a few hours) and as a result, the rollback will occur after the big select query has finished. So, I can't add the row to `data.person` for several hours (The second time I try to insert, I get a timeout exception because it waits for the lock to be released...).

I have read that I can use the function `pg_terminate_backend` in PostgreSQL to terminate the query, and so I can execute the insert query the second time.

My questions are :

1) How safe it is?

2) How common this solution is?

3) Is there a safer solution that JDBC or PostgreSQL provide?

Comment: you can set timeout for postgresql server
have a look here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-it-possible-to-limit-timeout-on-postgres-server

because your close function only closes your java client connection with DB.

Comment: thanks @VadymMotsukh , but It wont be right for my project. I only need timeout on the connections with this PGPoolingDataSource . For other connections, it is ok that they will run for some hours.

Comment: check that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291456/heroku-postgres-terminate-hung-query-idle-in-transaction/11292126#11292126

you can try "pg_cancel_backend" for soft stop query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_terminate_backend` will work and is the safe and correct procedure if you want to interrupt the query and close the database connection.

There is also `pg_cancel_backend` which will interrupt the query but leave the connection open.

These functions require that you know the process ID of the session backend process, which you can get with the `pg_backend_pid` function.

You must run these statements on a different database connection than the original one!

Another, probably simpler method is to set the `statement_timeout`. This can be set in the configuration file or for an individual session or transaction. To set it for a transaction, use:

```sql
BEGIN;  -- in JDBC, use setAutoCommit(false)
SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 30000;  -- in milliseconds
SELECT /* your query */;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks! helped a lot :)