# What happens to a transaction In Postgres, when a PHP or Python script crashes before transaction is committed?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

1. What happens to a transaction In Postgres, when a PHP or Python script crashes before transaction is committed. Is the transaction automatically rolled back and if not then what is the mechanism to rollback such an interrupted transaction. Is Postgress patrolling open connections and when a connection is lost a transaction is rolled back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminate hung query (idle in transaction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291456/terminate-hung-query-idle-in-transaction)

Comment: @ snakecharmerb Not really, the question you are referring to is 10 years old. A lot of changes where implemented into Postgres since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general algoritm used in RDBMS for transaction execution id [ARIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_Recovery_and_Isolation_Exploiting_Semantics). PosTgreSQL, like Oracle, SQL Server ... uses ARIES.

This mechanism guarantees that the transaction must always be finalized by a COMMIT (validation) or a ROLLBACK (cancellation), whatever the circumstances, even in the event of a breakdown of the SQL server. In the simpler case, of the application failure, either the transaction was validated because it was completed, but the client computer could not show it because the failure occurred just when displaying the result (rare in practice), either the transaction was canceled because the SQL server saw that the link with the client station was broken (most frequent case).

Comment: I believe ARIES refers to database crash and not to application crash. These are completely separate problems.

Comment: Database crash does not really exists, except when log file is full. Instance crash (that PG name it "cluster") yes...  Every transaction always finishes in any circumstances by a COMMIT or a ROLLBACK. That is the purpose of the transaction log... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81408/is-a-postgres-long-running-query-aborted-if-the-connection-is-lost-broken

Comment: The issue is not when transaction commits or rolls back but when script crashes without explicitly issuing neither COMMIT nor ROLLBACK.

Comment: I reapeat myself : when an application crashes and no COMMIT or ROLLBACK has been sent by the application code, then a forced ROLLBACK is internaly done by the RDBMS because the netwok link between client application and server has been broken... Is it clear ? So any transaction always finsih by a COMMIT or a ROLLBACK ... !